# How to generate good random seed for a random generator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, random, seed

I certainly can't use the random generator for that. Currently I'm creating a CRC32 hash from unixtime()+microtime().

Are there any smarter methods than hashing time()+microtime() ?

I am not fully satisfied from the results though, I expected it to be more random, but I can see strong patterns in it, until I added more calls to MicroTime() but it gets a lot slower, so I'm looking for some optimal way of doing this.

This silly code generates the best output I could make so far, the calculations were necessary or I could see some patterns in the output:

```
starthash(crc32);
    addtohash(crc32, MicroTime());
    addtohash(crc32, time(NULL)); // 64bit
    addtohash(crc32, MicroTime()/13.37f);
    addtohash(crc32, (10.0f-MicroTime())*1337.0f);
    addtohash(crc32, (11130.0f-MicroTime())/1313137.0f);
endhash(crc32);
```

MicroTime() returns microseconds elapsed from program start. I have overloaded the addtohash() to every possible type.

I would rather take non-library solutions, it's just ~10 lines of code probably anyways, I don't want to install huge library because of something I don't actually need that much, and I'm more interested in the code than just using it from a function call.

Comment: How cross platform should it be? :)

Comment: Whether the seed is "good" or not depends what you use the pseudo-random data for. If your only requirement is that the PRNG outputs different data at different times, then using the time is fine. But to seed a PRNG once each time the program runs, you may as well use CryptGenRandom.

Comment: A good cryprographic rng should have seeding built-in. Any other rng doesn't need this.

Comment: @Jack, currently i would be satisfied with Windows solution only, but linux+mac wouldnt hurt ;)

Comment: @SteveJessop, I might seed it multiple times in the program's execution time, not just once. I used to use time() for seed, but i noticed it couldnt keep up with my .exe clicking speed, so i decided to make it more random ;) Nevertheless, this has nothing to do with the current question.

Comment: Regarding the edit: if the output of the PRNG "isn't random", then that's nothing to do with the seed. The problem is the PRNG algorithm itself, or as you say maybe the PRNG output "is random", but the use you put it to conceals this. That said, if you pick 16.7 million colors at random from a palette of 16.7m, then how many distinct values do you expect? I haven't worked it out, but 10.5m seems within a reasonable distance of par.

Comment: @SteveJessop, you are right, i just tested with xor128 random values, and it gave around the same results, so i guess its pretty good then! it was stupid from me to expect to fill the whole range, heh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in any doubt, get your seed from `CryptGenRandom` on Windows, or by reading from `dev/random` or `dev/urandom` on *NIX systems.

This might be overkill for your purposes, but unless it causes performance problems there's no point messing with low-entropy sources like the time.

It's unlikely to be underkill. And if you're writing code with a real need for high-quality secure random data, and didn't bother mentioning that in the question, well, you get what you deserve ;-)

Comment: Tested, looks good(er?!), ~2x slower though. How does this do it, if not with time? (thats the part im interested into).

Comment: @Rookie So what if it's slower.  You're only going to seed the generator once per program run.  (Otherwise: I've had good results by hashing the results of `time()` and `getpid()`/`GetCurrentProcessId()`.  But nowhere near as good as with the solution Steve is suggesting.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, not really just once. but yeah the speed isnt that important, just interested in whats going on, why is it so slow and could it be made faster, and why not. Although, i think i will stick with `CryptGenRandom` because it can generate my xor128 seed in one run by just telling it to create 16 bytes instead of 4, i think it might even be faster then too.

Comment: @Rookie: `CryptGenRandom` draws on a number of different sources, including the time. Some of them are only available to the OS by pestering device drivers in a very non-portable way.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for lfsr & pseudorandom generators.. usually this is a hardwre solution but you can implement easily your own software lfsr

Comment: doesnt linear feedback shift register work like my current crc32 hash?

Comment: yes, crc calculations are based on lfsr. I suggested to use one extra lfsr (which you can configure as you want (length, initial seed, polyonym etc)) to work as pseudorandom number generator. This could be the input data on which you calculate the crc or whatever you need.